# How to select specific form element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two form like this:

```
<form id='form1' name='form1'>
  <input name='name' id='name'>
  <input name='name2' id='name2'>
</form>

<form id='form2' name='form2'>
  <input name='name' id='name'>
  <input name='name2' id='name2'>
</form>
```

Now I want to insert text in **name** field of **form2**. I am using [following jQuery code](http://jsfiddle.net/BNXuw/) but it fill **name** field of **form1**.

```
$("#name").val('Hello World!');
```

So how to select specific form elements only?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

It isn't valid to have the same ID twice, that's why `#name` only finds the first one.

You can try:

```
$("#form2 input").val('Hello World!');
```

Or,

```
$("#form2 input[name=name]").val('Hello World!');
```

If you're stuck with an invalid page and want to select all `#name`s, you can use the attribute selector on the id:

```
$("input[id=name]").val('Hello World!');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. One more thing, What if I want to select two fields of a specific form using multiple selector.

Comment: `$( '#formId field1Id, #formId field2Id' )`

Comment: @Awan - Another option is `$('#form2 input')` for all input fields, or `$('#form2 input').filter('[name=name1], [name=name2]')`

Comment: @charliegriefer - of course, you'll need `#field1Id` and `#field2Id`, and I'm not sure how that would behave with duplicated IDs.

Comment: @Kobi d'oH!  You're absolutely correct.  I forgot the hashes.  Editing now :)  Regarding the duplicate IDs, I thought the question was generic, and not specific to this particular example of invalid markup :)

Comment: Well, if the ID is unique, you don't really care in which form it is `:)`. But it is common enough to write scripts for existing pages, so this issue does come up.

Comment: Good point on the ID.  It's 5:30am.  I should probably stop trying to answer questions and hit the sack.  I blame sleep depravation :)

Comment: with many elements use $("#form2").find("#id1,#Id2#id3") if they are not direct childrens of form2, or $("#form2").children("#id1,#Id2#id3") if they are

Answer (score 13):

I prefer an id descendant selector of your #form2, like this:

```
$("#form2 #name").val("Hello World!");
```

http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Answer (score 9):

although it is  invalid html but you can use selector context to limit your selector 
in your case it would be like  :

`$("input[name='name']" , "#form2").val("Hello World! ");`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context

Comment: It's worth noting that `$('input[name=name]','#form2').val('Hello World!');` is translated, internally, by jQuery to `$('#form2').find('input[name=name]').val('Hello World!')` (see: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) for details.)

Comment: You forgot the quotation marks in the name part- With out them i get a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is about setting a input but just in case if you want to set a combobox then (I search net for it and didn't find anything and this place seems a right place to guide others)

If you had a form with ID attribute set (e.g. frm1) and 
you wanted to set a specific specific combobox, with no ID set but name attribute set (e.g. district); then use

```js
$("#frm1 select[name='district'] option[value='NWFP']").attr('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="frm1">
        <select name="district">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Area ...</option>
            <option value="NWFP">NWFP</option>
            <option value="FATA">FATA</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#name", '#form2').val("Hello World")
```