# jquery - how change input selector with id tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML input but I need to change the value attribute with jQuery.

My HTML code :

```
<input id="idelement" autocomplete="off" value="120" type="text"/>
```

And my jQuery code :

```
$('input[id="idelement"]').val("351");
```

can you help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select specific form element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387319/how-to-select-specific-form-element-in-jquery)

Comment: `$("#idelement").val("351");`

Answer (score 1):

It works; just make sure you included jQuery, and that you have that element on your HTML :

```
$('input[id="idelement"]').val("351"); // valid
```

Alternatively, you can use a selector (like you would on a css stylesheet) :

```
$('input#idelement').val("351"); // valid
// Or: (If you're sure it's an input)
$('#idelement').val("351"); // valid
```

Comment: Tnx
its Correct but when i change id with this code after 1 or 2 second its change agane back to previous value

Comment: How do you change it?

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing this

`$("[id*='idelement]").val("351");`

Comment: While that works, it may affect other elements as well, e.g : `<input id="idelement2"><input id="idelement3">` will change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#idelement').val("351");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='form' name='form'>
    <input id="idelement" name=="idelement" autocomplete="off" value="120" type="text" />
</form>

$("#form input").val('351');
```

or

```
$("#form input[name=idelement]").val('351');
```

```js
$("#form input").val('351');
//or
$("input[id=idelement]").val('351');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form' name='form'>
        <input id="idelement" name=="idelement" autocomplete="off" value="120" type="text" />
    </form>
```

For more details visit:[how to select specific form element in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387319/how-to-select-specific-form-element-in-jquery)