# Laravel ajax won't act properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to save data by ajax the issue is that i'm getting same id over and over.

## Code

how my data append on blade

```
    if(value1['type'] == 'textfield'){
      var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
      var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
      my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><input id="text_dec" name="text_dec[]" placeholder="text field" class="text_dec form-control"></div>';
      my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsavee" class="custmodalsavee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
      my_row.html(my_html);
      $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
}else if(value1['type'] == 'textareafield'){
       var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
       var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
       my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><textarea id="longtext_dec" name="longtext_dec[]" placeholder="text area field" class="longtext_dec form-control"></textarea></div>';
       my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsavee" class="custmodalsavee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
       my_row.html(my_html);
       $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
}
```

`script`

```
<script>
$("body").on("click", ".custmodalsavee", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('admin/addnewcustomsubspecifications') }}",
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': $('#product_id').val(),
          'specification_id': $("#specification_id").val(),
          'text_dec': $('.text_dec').val(),
          'longtext_dec': $('.longtext_dec').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $('#custspacmsg').append('<span class="text-success">Custom Specification added successfully in your product!</span>').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            console.log('done!');
            $('.myButton').css('display', 'none');
            $('.myButtonlong').css('display', 'none');
            $('.removebtn').css('display', 'none');
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error!');
        }
      });
});
</script>
```

## Explanation

This is how my `specification_id` will append:

```
<input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" value="66" type="hidden">
```

other one for example

```
<input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" value="67" type="hidden">
```

As you see id's are different but each time i save my data it uses first form specification_id `66` so when I attempt to save data with specification_id `67` it also saves for `66`.

> PS: Maybe it worth to mention (not sure) that I have several script
>   that runs on body
>
> ```
> $("body").on("click", ".....", function(e){
> ```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select specific form element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387319/how-to-select-specific-form-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

I added

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
```

and changed my `specification_id` to:

```
'specification_id': $(this).closest('form').find('#specification_id').val(),
```

now it's working as it supposed to.